# Wordpress sub categories redirecting to blog

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, categories

I have a problem with my sub categories not linking to their correct page.

Here is the link and i will walk you through to recreate what i'm getting.

http://fantastickids.co.za/

On the home page click on "child care"
Then on the childcare page click on "after school care"
You will land on a blank blog page.

This is the page it is supposed to go to

[Correct page](http://fantastickids.co.za/company_category/after-school-care/?s&cat=after-school-care&search_simple=Search%20Now)

I also noticed that the "after school care" link tries to go to but brings up a blog.

http://fantastickids.co.za/company_category/after-school-care/

And the one that works is doing a search i think :/

http://fantastickids.co.za/company_category/after-school-care/?s&cat=after-school-care&search_simple=Search+Now

This was apparently created by another outsourced developer but he has since vanished

If anyone has some insight i would love to hear what you think is going on and possible solutions

Thank you for the help in advance.

If this question is in the wrong place please point me where to add it.